# PHP variable name includes variable

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to set variables $upkeep_1, $upkeep_2, etc using a loop.
I have this code:

```
$sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM houses_db", $db); 
while ($rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2)) {
   $upkeep_{$rs2[type]} = (int) $rs2[upkeep]; 
   }

echo $upkeep_3 . "<br>";
```

$rs2[type] is a number field, starting at one and going up to 8.

This code outputs nothing though, despite $rs[upkeep] being 3000. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Start with giving your variables meaningful names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not using an array?

```
$sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM houses_db", $db); 
while ($rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2)) {
    $upkeep[$rs2['type']] = (int) $rs2['upkeep']; 
}

echo $upkeep[3] . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to do this? Do you know about arrays :) ?

Anyway try something like this:

```
$sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM houses_db", $db); 
while ($rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2)) {
   eval("$upkeep_".$rs2[type]." = (int) ".$rs2[upkeep].""); 
}

echo $upkeep_3 . "<br>";
```

Comment: There's that "What the OP asked_for/wanted/needed" problem you describe on your about page

Comment: There is NOTHING like it in your answer.